# How to run 'mlflow run -e train_model --experiment_name' exp_name . without the experiment_name flag

Tags: python, command-line-interface, mlflow

I have the MLProject set up and on my python script, I have already set the experiment name by mlflow.set_experiment("exp_name"), so how can I run the mlflow run on cli without specifying the experiment_name flag?

Currently..

> mlflow run -e train_model --experiment_name' exp_name .

But I want to run it like this:

> mlflow run -e train_model .

Comment: if you have the code for mlflow experiment setup already, just run it as a normal python script. "python filename.py"

Comment: I have some requirements that I need to run the MLProject